# Python - Create a list of objects based on counts of another list of objects

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of objects and I want to create another list of items but grouped by "Name" and two fields which are number of instances of a particular instance type.
I have this :

```
result = [
    {"Name": "Foo", "Type": "A", "RandomColumn1": "1"},
    {"Name": "Bar", "Type": "B", "RandomColumn2": "2"},
    {"Name": "Foo", "Type": "A", "RandomColumn3": "3"},
    {"Name": "Bar", "Type": "A", "RandomColumn4": "4"},
    {"Name": "Foo", "Type": "B", "RandomColumn5": "5"},
]
```

I am trying to get a count of the number of different "Type" columns whilst discarding any other column - RandomColumnX in this case.

I want the above to come out like this:

```
[{"Name": "Foo", "A": 2, "B": 1}, {"Name": "Bar", "A": 1, "B": 1}]
```

I tried doing something like this :

```
group_requests = [{
    "Name": key,
    "A": len([d for d in list(value) if d.get('Type') == 'A']),
    "B": len([y for y in list(value) if y['Type'] == 'B']),
} for key, value in groupby(result, key=lambda x: x['Name'])]
```

However, it does not count the values in the "B" column and the count for this key is always 0.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: @VishalSingh I thought that might be the case... is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mistake 1.**
In order for the `itertools.groupby` to work your input iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function.

```
result = sorted(result, key=lambda x: x["Name"])
```

**Mistake 2.**
The returned group i.e `value` is itself an iterator, so you need to save the output in order to iterate over it multiple times.

```
group_requests = []
for key, value in itertools.groupby(result, key=lambda x: x["Name"]):
    value = list(value)  # save the output
    temp = {
        "Name": key,
        "A": len([d for d in value if d.get("Type") == "A"]),
        "B": len([y for y in value if y["Type"] == "B"]),
    }
    group_requests.append(temp)
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants without list comprehension. It can be achieve like this

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = [{"Name": "Foo", "Type": "A", "RandomColumn1": "1"},
    {"Name": "Bar", "Type": "B", "RandomColumn2": "2"},
    {"Name": "Foo", "Type": "A", "RandomColumn3": "3"},
    {"Name": "Bar", "Type": "A", "RandomColumn4": "4"},
    {"Name": "Foo", "Type": "B", "RandomColumn5": "5"}]

group_requests = []

counterA = defaultdict(int)
counterB = defaultdict(int)
names = set()

for val in result:
    name = val["Name"]
    type = val["Type"]
    
    if type == "A":
        counterA[name] += 1
    else:
        counterB[name] += 1

    names.add(name)

for name in names:
    group_requests.append({
        "Name": name,
        "A": counterA[name],
        "B": counterB[name]
    })

print(group_requests)
```